# How can i add open sans light font in my ckeditor fonts dropdown?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ckeditor, wysiwyg, ng-ckeditor

I am using ckeditor 4.6.1 and ng-ckeditor directive-0.2.1. 
By default the current ckeditor version shows list of fonts. How can I add open-sans font in that dropdown?